# Sql-Server UniqueIntList type for java

Tags: sql-server, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, mssql-jdbc

I am having a stored procedure (sp) which uses UniqueIntList type in the sql server. I want to call this sp from java using spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

sql server sp execution details

```
DECLARE @M dbo.UniqueIntList 
INSERT INTO @M VALUES (1),(2),(6)

exec usp_mysp @M

GO
```

Below is how I am executing it using java

```
private static final String SQL_SP = "usp_mysp :myVar";
MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    mapSqlParameterSource.addValue("myVar", myList); // my list is List<Integer>
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(SQL_SP, mapSqlParameterSource, (q, i) -> {
        // ... //
    });
```

While doing this, I am getting **Procedure or function has too many arguments specified** and I figured out that this is due to the UniqueIntList type in the sql server.

So I would like to know how exactly shall I pass the values in the map for the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Comment: Did you follow the docs on using a Table-valued parameter from Java: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I am not aware about that, but can you tell me, how will that help me in overcoming the UniqueIntList?

Comment: UniqueIntList is a user-defined table type.  And so to call a stored procedure with that type as a parameter, you use a table-valued parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @David Browne in the comments, I had put some research on Table-valued parameter and this [Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/wiki/Using-TVP-with-stored-procedure-in-Spring-framework) here helped to understand how can I achieve it using spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate for the ms-sql server